# Return from module is undefined

Tags: node.js, module

Hi I made a module and when I try to return the song name it is just undefined, the console.log just before it works though so I'm a little confused. The line after  console.log(`"${songName}" by ${artistsList}`) is where the issue is, I try to return `"${songName}" by ${artistsList}` but the return is just undefined so I am a little stuck on why

Code: (This is the spotify.js module)
I call it with const Spotify = require("./spotify.js"), everything works up until I need to just return the song name using the Spotify.request() function

```
const axios = require("axios");

module.exports = {
    token: "",
    ref: "",
    refresh: function () {
      axios({
        method: "post", //you can set what request you want to be
        url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
        data:
          `grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=${this.ref}`,
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            "Basic ",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }
      }).then(response => {
        this.token = response.data.access_token
        console.log(`Successfully refreshed token ${module.exports.token}`);
      });
    },
    analyseSong: function (data) {
      console.log(data)
      const x = data;
      //console.log(x)
      if (x.is_playing) {
        const songNameMatch = x.item.name.split("(");
        var songName = x.item.name;
        try {
          const letter = songNameMatch[1].charAt(0);
          letter.toLowerCase() == "f" ||
            songNameMatch[1].toLowerCase().match(/^with/)
            ? (songName = songNameMatch[0].trim())
            : false;
        } catch (err) {
          false;
        }
        var artistArray = [];
        var artist;
        const artists = x.item.artists;
        //console.log(token)
        for (artist in artists) {
          artistArray.push(x.item.artists[artist].name);
        }
  
        //console.log(artistArray)
  
        const artistsList = artistArray.join(", ");
        //console.log(artistsList)
        //console.log(`Currently playing: ${songName} - ${artistsList}`);
        console.log(`"${songName}" by ${artistsList}`)
        return `"${songName}" by ${artistsList}`;
      } else {
        return `Not currently listening to a song`;
      }
    },
    request: function () {
      axios
        .get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing", {
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          module.exports.analyseSong(response.data);
        })
    },
  }
```

Comment: You show a bunch of code that ends up as exports, but you don't show any code that actually calls some of this code and  attempts to get a return value.  Please show code that calls one of these exported functions and show where you're trying to use a return value.  FYI, neither the `refresh()` or `request()` functions have ANY return value so it's no surprise that a caller can't get any direct results.

Comment: Its the request() function that takes the data and does analyseSong, I want to return the song name but I get undefine when I try to call it and return as shown in the code. So I'm doing X=Spotify.request() trying to get the song name as X so I can output using IRC chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I'm doing `X=Spotify.request()` trying to get the song name as X so I can output using IRC chat

There are a couple problems.  `.request()` has no return value at all.  So, it will never return anything other than `undefined`.  You can fix that like this by adding two `return` statements, the first to return the promise itself and the second to make the return value from `analyseSong()` be the resolved value of that promise:

```
request: function () {
  return axios
    .get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing", {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}` }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      return module.exports.analyseSong(response.data);
    })
},
```

Now `Spotify.request()` will return a promise that will resolve with the value returned from `.analyseSong(response.data)`.  You would use that promise like this:

```
Spotify.request().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```